# Should I use make or makes for this sentence

Tags: grammatical-number

> Every second of it only **make** / **makes** it worse

I'm trying to figure out which of the two I should use for the sentence above.

Comment: 'Makes' since 'second' is singular.

Comment: I'd like to advise you to visit our sister site [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), but please make sure you take the [tour](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit their [Help Center](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help) before posting any question.

Answer (score 2):

You should use 'makes'.

However the sentence:
"Every second of it only makes it worse"

... is unclear without context. Using two instances of "it" is confusing because the reader needs to guess what each it refers to.

To be more clear you could replace each "it" with more specific details or emotive words.